# How to put three icons side by side in Python using PyQt4?

Tags: python, window, icons, pyqt4

I wrote a small program in Python and for now I have 3 buttons side by side and I am able to put an icon on each of them. How to display only icons instead of buttons with icons? I hope you know what I mean. I want to remove my buttons and display icons only.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
 def __init__(self):
  super(Example, self).__init__()
  self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):
  self.statusBar().showMessage('Start the game!')
  self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
  panel = QtGui.QWidget()
  grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
  p1 = QtGui.QPushButton("")
  p1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image1.jpg'))
  p2 = QtGui.QPushButton("")
  p2.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image2.jpg'))
  p3 = QtGui.QPushButton("")
  p3.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image3.jpg'))

  p1.setMaximumHeight(1000)
  p2.setMaximumHeight(1000)
  p3.setMaximumHeight(1000)

  grid.addWidget(p1,0,0)
  grid.addWidget(p2,0,1)
  grid.addWidget(p3,0,2)

  panel.setLayout(grid)
  self.setCentralWidget(panel)
  self.setWindowTitle('MyGame')    
  self.show()

def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `.setGeometry` method on your QLabel (`lbl`)

If you want the image to be on the far right, you could add a space item to your HBoxLayout like this:

```
lbl.setGeometry(0,0,100,100)
spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
hbox.addItem(spacerItem)
```

Comment: Could you use it on my example code with one icon? I tried to use that function, but it doesn't change the place of my icon.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the lbl.move command since the .setGeometry command will move the picture within the widget with the first two values. I got your code to work fine with adding `lbl.setGeometry(0,0,100,100)` under your `.setPixmap` line.

Comment: Code is working but it doesn't change the place of the image in my window and I don't know why.